# How to hide the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

On a few occasions the keyboard has popped up and refused to disappear. On Android you can hold down the menu button to show/hide the keyboard. Does Windows Phone 7 have a similar thing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pressing the back button hides the keyboard. You can also tap somewhere on the screen where is no input field

Comment: It must have been a bug because at the time tapping somewhere else didn't work (didn't try the back button).

Comment: It is not exaclty somewhere. If you click in a label and the person who program that label did the focus goes to the text field the keyboard doesn't hide. But if you click where there aren't nothing it need to hide.

Comment: Must have been because at the time tapping somewhere else didn't work try the back button